# Где взять dataset лиц?

Tags: база-данных, нейронные-сети

где можно взять dataset лиц, черно белых картинок в которых четко по центру лицо, и чтоб картинки были одинакогого размера

Comment: https://thispersondoesnotexist.com/

Answer (score -1):

https://kaggle.com/datasets - датасеты на разные тематики, также есть лица ! Также можно написать тем кто делает датасеты, задать вопрос или попросить сделать датасет !